# Executing triggers in Oracle for copying the old values to a Mirror table

Tags: oracle, triggers

We are trying to copy the current row of a table to mirror table by using a trigger before delete / update. Below is the working query

```
 BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE 
  ON CurrentTable FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO MirrorTable
 ( EMPFIRSTNAME,
   EMPLASTNAME,
   CELLNO,
   SALARY
    )
VALUES
 ( :old.EMPFIRSTNAME,
   :old.EMPLASTNAME,
   :old.CELLNO,
   :old.SALARY
    ); 
END;
```

But the problem is we have more than 50 coulmns in the current table and dont want to mention all those column names. Is there a way to select all coulmns like
 :old.*

```
SELECT  * INTO MirrorTable FROM CurrentTable
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: It will be a great aid to your coding if you use an editor with a column-editing mode. Ultraedit and sublime Text, for example, make it very easy to copy a long column of names (NAME_1 NAME2 etc) and then edit it to another column of entries such as "Coalesce(Sum(NAME_1),0) sum_of_NAME_01,". It will speed you up and eliminate typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, no.  You'll need to list all the columns.

- You could, of course, dynamically generate the trigger code pulling the column names from `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.  But that is going to be dramatically more work than simply typing in 50 column names.
- If your table happens to be an object table, `:new` would be an instance of that object so you could insert that.  But it would be rather rare to have an object table.

Answer (score 1):

If your 'current' and 'mirror' tables have **EXACTLY** the same structure you may be able to use something like

```
INSERT INTO MirrorTable
  SELECT *
    FROM CurrentTable
    WHERE CurrentTable.primary_key_column = :old.primary_key_column
```

Honestly, I think that this is a poor choice and wouldn't do it, but it's a more-or-less free world and you're free (more or less :-) to make your own choices.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: In general, if you query `CurrentTable` in a row-level trigger defined on `CurrentTable`, you will generally get a mutating table error.  The exception is if every single insert will always be a single-row insert with an `INSERT ... VALUES` but that is not particularly realistic.

Comment: @JustinCave: doh!  Forgot we were talking about a trigger on CurrentTable.  In that case I'd say use a compound trigger.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've been writing the same stuff and used this to generate the code:

SQL> set pagesize 0

SQL> select ':old.'||COLUMN_NAME||',' from all_tab_columns where table_name='BIGTABLE' and owner='BOB';

:old.COL1,

:old.COL2,

:old.COL3,

:old.COL4,

:old.COL5,

...

If you feed all columns, no need to mention them twice (and you may use NULL for empty columns):

INSERT INTO bigtable VALUES (

:old.COL1,

:old.COL2,

:old.COL3,

:old.COL4,

:old.COL5,

NULL,

NULL);

people writing tables with that many columns should have no desserts ;-)